# Get class type?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-4.0

Given

```
public class A
{
    public static void Foo()
    {
        // get typeof(B)
    }
}

public class B : A
{

}
```

Is it possible for `B.Foo()` to get `typeof(B)` in .NET 4? Note that `Foo` is static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible, [as dtb explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898656/get-class-type/3898667#3898667).

One alternative is to make `A` generic like so:

```
public class A<T>
{
    public static void Foo()
    {
        // use typeof(T)
    }
}

public class B : A<B>
{
}
```

Another possibility is to make the `A.Foo` method generic and then provide stub methods in the derived types that then call the "base" iplementation.

I'm not keen on this pattern. It's probably only worthwhile if you absolutely need to keep the `B.Foo` calling convention, you can't make `A` itself generic, and you have lots of shared logic inside `A.Foo` that you don't want to repeat in your derived types.

```
public class A
{
    protected static void Foo<T>()
    {
        // use typeof(T)
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public static void Foo()
    {
        A.Foo<B>();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the same solution I wound up discovering :) (the first one). Works pretty well! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between `A.Foo()` and `B.Foo()`. The compiler emits a call to `A.Foo()` in both cases. So, no, there is no way to detect if `Foo` was called as `A.Foo()` or `B.Foo()`.